# My function to extract totals is exhausting my input file for future reading

Tags: python, csv

The client includes 3 rows at the bottom that contain totals for me to reconcile against in my program.  Only problem is that my program is exhausting the input file with readlines() before it can do anything else.  Is there a way to keep the file from being exhausted during my get_recon_total function call?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pre_process.py
import csv
import sys


def main():
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    with open(infile, 'rbU') as in_obj:
        # Create reader object, get fieldnames for later on
        reader, fieldnames = open_reader(in_obj)

        nav_tot_cnt, nav_rec_cnt, nav_erec_cnt = get_recon_totals(in_obj)
        print nav_tot_cnt, nav_rec_cnt, nav_erec_cnt

        # This switches the dictionary to a sorted list... necessary??
        reader_list = sorted(reader, key=lambda key: (key['PEOPLE_ID'], 
                                                 key['DON_DATE']))

        # Create a list to contain section header information                                        
        header_list = create_header_list(reader_list)

        # Create dictionary that contains header list as the key,
        # then all rows that match as a list of dictionaries.
        master_dict = map_data(header_list, reader_list)

        # Write data to processed file, create recon counts to compare 
        # to footer record
        tot_cnt, rec_cnt, erec_cnt = write_data(master_dict, outfile, fieldnames)
        print tot_cnt, rec_cnt, erec_cnt


def open_reader(file_obj):
    '''
    Uses DictReader from the csv module to take the first header line
    as the fieldnames, then applies them to each element in the file.
    Returns the DictReader object and the fieldnames being used (used
    later when data is printed out with DictWriter.)
    '''
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    return reader, reader.fieldnames


def create_header_list(in_obj):
    p_id_list = []
    for row in in_obj:
        if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) not in p_id_list:
            p_id_list.append((row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']))
    return p_id_list


def map_data(header_list, data_obj):
    master_dict = {}
    client_section_list = []
    for element in header_list:
        for row in data_obj:
            if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) == element:
                client_section_list.append(row)
        element = list(element)
        element_list = [client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['ND_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD'],
                    client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD']
                    ]
        try:
            element_list.append((float(client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD']) +
                                 float(client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD'])
                                 ))
        except ValueError:
            pass

        element.extend(element_list)
        element = tuple(element)
        master_dict[element] = client_section_list
        client_section_list = []
    return master_dict


def write_data(in_obj, outfile, in_fieldnames):
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as writer_outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(writer_outfile, delimiter=',')
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(writer_outfile,
                                     fieldnames=in_fieldnames,
                                     extrasaction='ignore')
        tot_cnt = 0
        rec_cnt = 0
        email_cnt = 0
        for k, v in in_obj.iteritems():
            writer_outfile.write(' -01- ')
            writer.writerow(k)
            rec_cnt += 1
            for i, e in enumerate(v):
                if v[i]['INT_CODE_EX0006'] != '' or v[i]['INT_CODE_EX0028'] != '':
                    email_cnt += 1
                writer_outfile.write(' -02- ')
                dict_writer.writerow(e)
                tot_cnt += 1
        return tot_cnt, rec_cnt, email_cnt


def get_recon_totals(in_obj):
    print in_obj
    client_tot_cnt = 0
    client_rec_cnt = 0
    client_erec_cnt = 0

    for line in in_obj.readlines():
        line = line.split(',')
        if line[0] == 'T' and line[1] == 'Total Amount':
            print 'Total Amount found.'
            client_tot_cnt = line[2]
        elif line[0] == 'T' and line[1] == 'Receipt Count':
            print 'Receipt Count found.'
            client_rec_cnt = line[2]
        elif line[0] == 'T' and line[1] == 'Email Receipt Count':
            print 'E-Receipt Count Found.'
            client_erec_cnt = line[2]
    return client_tot_cnt, client_rec_cnt, client_erec_cnt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: No, that's how file iterators work. If you've read the content into a list, why does it matter that the iterator is exhausted?

Comment: Because I then need to use the information in the file to read into `DictReader`.  Should I do that at the same time I'm finding recon totals?

Comment: Why not just give the list of lines to the `DictReader`? Why read the file more than once?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So would that be something like creating a list of lines in my `get_recon_total` function to then pass into my `open_reader` function to feed into my `DictReader`?  I'm a bit inexperienced with what exactly I can feed `DictReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is not very large, you can convert reader generator to a list of dcitonary , by calling `list()` on `reader` and then use it in your code instead of trying to read from the file directly.

Example -

```
def main():
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    with open(infile, 'rbU') as in_obj:
        # Create reader object, get fieldnames for later on
        reader, fieldnames = open_reader(in_obj)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        nav_tot_cnt, nav_rec_cnt, nav_erec_cnt = get_recon_totals(reader_list)
        print nav_tot_cnt, nav_rec_cnt, nav_erec_cnt

        # This switches the dictionary to a sorted list... necessary??
        reader_list = sorted(reader_list, key=lambda key: (key['PEOPLE_ID'], 
                                                 key['DON_DATE']))
        .
        .
def get_recon_totals(reader_list):
    print in_obj
    client_tot_cnt = 0
    client_rec_cnt = 0
    client_erec_cnt = 0

    for line in reader_list: #line here is a dict
        if line[<fieldname for first column>] == 'T' and line[<fieldname for secondcolumn>] == 'Total Amount':
            print 'Total Amount found.'
            client_tot_cnt = line[<fieldname for third column>]
        .
        .                                                          #continued like above
        .
    return client_tot_cnt, client_rec_cnt, client_erec_cnt
```